# SQL Server : copy from one table to another where accountID matches

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables: `tblAccounts` and `tblOrders`. How do I copy the data in column `VENUE` in `tblOrders` to the new column I've just set up in `tblAccounts` also called `VENUE` but where the account ID matches.

I was going to try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblaccounts (venue) 
    SELECT venue 
    FROM tblorders 
    WHERE tblorders.accountID = tblaccounts.accountID
```

If that makes sense?

The tables are different sizes so I can't just copy it all across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to copy the value of column: `venue` from `tblOrders` to `tblAccounts`, you should update `tblAccounts` instead of inserting as following.

```
UPDATE tblAccounts
SET
[venue] =y.[venue]
FROM tblAccounts INNER JOIN tblOrders y
ON
tblAccounts.[accountID] = y.[accountID]
```